How do you make WebStorm/IntelliJ use a specific tsconfig file for specific files for code inspection?
I want to deactivate tsconfig's noUncheckedIndexedAccess flag for an Angular project's spec-files. The tests are compiling and running, but WebStorm still shows the particular code spots in the spec files as if the flag was turned on.
tsconfig.json
{
  ...,
  "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
}

tsconfig.spec.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine"],
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

WebStorm seems to ignore the file's include-array or the relevant configuration in angular.json:
{
  ...,
  "projects": {  "projectName": {  "architect": {
    "test": {
      ...,
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  }}}
}

How do I do that / Is this a bug?
